# What's the use case for int32.Parse(String, IFormatProvider) over int32.Parse(String)?

Tags: c#

When would it make sense to use `int32.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`?

As far as I can tell, this and `int32.Parse(String)` uses `NumberStyles.Integer` anyway which only allows a plus, a minus, or digits, optionally surrounded by whitespace, so why does the locale format enter into the equation?

I know about thousand separators, but they don't matter because `NumberStyles.Integer` disallows them no matter your region.

Comment: Since you just edited the question. `int32.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` allows you to pass `NumberStyles.AllowThousand` and uses the current culture, if none is provided.

Comment: No, that is a different method, that is either `int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles)` or `int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)`. I am explicitly asking if there is a use case for the method where you can't specify `NumberStyles`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider if you have culture where negative sign is `M` (minus). I am pretty sure it doesn't exist but just consider that you have something like that. Then you can do:

```
string str = "M123";
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
culture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign = "M";
int number = Int32.Parse(str, culture);
```

This would result in `-123` as value.  This is where you can use `int32.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` overload. If you don't specify the culture, then it would use the current culture and would fail for the value `M123`.

---

*(Old Answer)*

It is useful with **string with thousand separator**

Consider the following example,

```
string str = "1,234,567";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
int number = Int32.Parse(str, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

This would result in an exception since `.` is the thousand separator in German culture.

For

```
 int number = Int32.Parse("1.234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

The above would parse successfully, since the German culture uses `.` as thousand separator.

But if you have current culture set as US then it would give an exception.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
int number = Int32.Parse("1.234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

See: [Int32.Parse Method (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f56zcx39.aspx)

> The provider parameter is an IFormatProvider implementation, **such as
>   a NumberFormatInfo or CultureInfo object**. The provider parameter
>   supplies culture-specific information about the format of s. If
>   provider is null, the NumberFormatInfo object for the current culture
>   is used.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes you have to explicitly allow thousand separator. like `int number2 = Int32.Parse("1.234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);`

Comment: And that is my question - what use is the overload that does _not_ let you specify the NumberStyle, but allows you to specify the culture?

Answer (score 3):

Well how about the thousand separators?
I think in USA they use ',' and in Greece they use '.'

USA: 1,000,000
Greece: 1.000.000

Comment: This is not the answer, because overload with only `IFormatProvider` also does not parse the separator.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else is also wondering about this 6 years later, there's still no point in using `Int32.ToString(IFormatProvider?)` or `Int32.Parse(String, IFormatProvider?)` since changing the culture makes no difference with the default format and `NumberStyles`.

You can run this simple test to verify:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;


class IntToStringTest
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
        var input = -123456789;
        var defaultOutput = input.ToString();

        var outputCulturePairs = cultures.Select(c => (Output: input.ToString(c), Culture: c));
        var parsedOutputs = outputCulturePairs.Select(p => Int32.Parse(p.Output, p.Culture));

        Console.WriteLine(outputCulturePairs.All(p => p.Output == defaultOutput));
        Console.WriteLine(parsedOutputs.All(o => o == input));
    }
}
```

Edit 8/8/2020: This is only true for .NET Framework. On .NET Core some Arabic cultures use the minus sign AFTER the value.

Comment: And what about thousands-separators as mentioned in the other answers?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The default "G" format for `ToString` doesn't output thousands-separators and the default `NumberStyles.Integer` doesn't include `AllowThousands`.  
Culture only starts to matter when you use other overloads that allow you to specify the input/output format.