# Format Exception was unhandled c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save a set of records in my desktop c# application and it appears to stop since one of the values was in the incorrect format.

Before saving, the system goes through these computations:

```
private void ComputeTotalWeight()
    {
        double TotalWeight;
        TotalWeight = ((Convert.ToInt32(txtSmall.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(txtMedium.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(txtLarge.Text)) + 
            (Convert.ToInt32(txtExtralarge.Text))) * .285;
        txtTotalweight.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", TotalWeight);

    }

    private void ComputeTagsCollars()
    {
        int TagsCollars;
        TagsCollars = Convert.ToInt32(txtSmall.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtMedium.Text) 
            + Convert.ToInt32(txtLarge.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtExtralarge.Text);
        txtTags.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", TagsCollars);
        txtCollars.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", TagsCollars);

    }
```

But once I save, it seems to be having a problem with the GrandTotal computation:

[image]

I suspect the error come from this computation:

```
private void ComputeGrandTotal()
    {
        double GrandTotal;
        GrandTotal = (((Convert.ToInt32(txtSmall.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtMedium.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtLarge.Text) + 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtExtralarge.Text)) * .285) * 315);

        double TagsCollars;
        TagsCollars = Convert.ToInt32(txtSmall.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtMedium.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtLarge.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtExtralarge.Text);
        txtTags.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", TagsCollars);
        txtCollars.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", TagsCollars);

        lblGrandtotal.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###,##0}", (GrandTotal + TagsCollars + TagsCollars));

    }
```

I've tried commenting out all GrandTotal related values and functions, and the records begin to save with no problem. Here's a copy of my save function:

```
private void InsertNewRecord()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand();
        cmdInsert.Connection = cn;
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QtySmall", Convert.ToInt32(txtSmall.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QtyMedium", Convert.ToInt32(txtMedium.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QtyLarge", Convert.ToInt32(txtLarge.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QtyExtralarge", Convert.ToInt32(txtExtralarge.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QtyTags", Convert.ToInt32(txtTags.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QtyCollars", Convert.ToInt32(txtCollars.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalWeight", Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalweight.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoWorkers", Convert.ToInt32(txtWorkersno.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoMachines", Convert.ToInt32(txtMachinesno.Text));
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BomStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpStart.Value;
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpEnd.Value;
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrandTotal", Convert.ToInt32(lblGrandtotal.Text));
        cmdInsert.CommandText = " INSERT INTO BillOfMaterials2 " + " (QtySmall, QtyMedium, QtyLarge, QtyExtralarge, QtyTags, QtyCollars, TotalWeight, NoWorkers, NoMachines, BomStatus, StartDate, EndDate, GrandTotal) VALUES (" + "@QtySmall, @QtyMedium, @QtyLarge, @QtyExtralarge, @QtyTags, @QtyCollars, @TotalWeight, @NoWorkers, @NoMachines, @BomStatus, @StartDate, @EndDate, @GrandTotal)";
        //cmdInsert.CommandText = "spInsertBom";



        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] - please read this guidance carefully and make sure to have *minimal* sample in the post (coming up with it may also solve your problem - not sure if it concerns you).

Comment: Your problem is only in `Convert.ToInt32(lblGrandtotal.Text)`, the rest of the code is not needed. Did you verify what string this method receives when you get the exception? It should be extremely easy to debug and find the cause.

Comment: @Andrew there is another line of code in the post that is needed - the one that creates the value.. (no idea why OP chose custom formatting for numbers, but they pay for it with inability to parse back).

Comment: (Spoiler - answer explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118376/whats-the-use-case-for-int32-parsestring-iformatprovider-over-int32-parsest - `int.Parse("1,234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, also you should be using culture-specific formatting for numbers to start with)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this is the code that creates the value: lblGrandtotal.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###,##0}", (GrandTotal + TagsCollars + TagsCollars));

Comment: thank you so much @AlexeiLevenkov :D

Comment: @Ron Reyes Read my comment and Krunal's comment - basically it boils down to tesxt that can not be converted to integer 1,234,567 is not the same as 1234567 notice one has comments the other not - if you use Int32.TryParse(myText, out myint) it would be obvious as the conversion would result in 0 and your question would be why 0 instead of - then the TryParse method info on MSDN would explain that clearly. Text that is not a number (0123456789) is text only and cannot be converted to integer with Convert.ToInt32(1,234,567) always fails, you must remove the format commas etc from the numbers.

Comment: @Ken that nailed it... thank you so so much!

Comment: @Ron Reyes - mark one of the answers that helped you resolve it as the answer it helps others later on to see the actual answer, and it is good etiquette.

Comment: will do! thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st I would not attempt converting a textbox.text value to Int32 using convert; better to use

```
Int32 myint = 0;
Int32.TryParse(textbox.text, out myint) ;
```

This ensures that the text can be converted to an integer and if not you get 0 as a returned out value.

Then in your save method - your @GrandTotal parameter is trying to save to what datatype ? - what is the type in your database ?? do they match - if not you will get a format exception your data (Type) is not the same Format (type) as the column type.

The op does not have a valid number in the text box he has this:

```
    lblGrandtotal.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###,##0}", 
(GrandTotal + TagsCollars + TagsCollars));
```

This is why the code where he sets the parameter value = lblGrandtotal.Text it is not a number it has formatting commas etc.. he needs to remove those to make it work, using Int.TryParse would easily reveal this.

Comment: If you'd actually read the question you know why code fails... Suggesting generic improvements should be done in comments.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov it might read like a generic improvement - but his code would not fail if he used TryParse - it fails because the string can not be converted to an integer.. in my code - he would get a different value than what he thought and could debug to see the values he is trying to convert. For some people it is easier to find a calculation issue, rather than a programming debug message.

Comment: It would not anything useful either (which most people call "does not work") - clearly OP expects valid number there (for good reason as they put number into that field to start with, also with strange formatting)

Comment: @Ken its saving to the int datatype in my database

Answer (score 1):

its starts here - first you are putting decimal in your format string with comma.

```
lblGrandtotal.Text = String.Format("**{0:#,###,##0}**", (GrandTotal + TagsCollars + TagsCollars));
```

also, later in your code you are storing INT int database, when its actually decimal.
and as mentioned by ken, use tryparse to convert the value from string to ....

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here some of the other posts touched on but, what really stands out (in my opinion) is you're not validating the input data, which is risky for many reasons, asking for future headaches and causing these issues. Also, there are standard numerical input controls you could use. If there's some reason you can't use them though, you should be validating the input and, if the data is not valid, handle it. Below is a quick way to validate and then handle invalid inputs.

```
private void ComputeGrandTotal()
{
    //Since there are values that need to be validated and converted to integers for use in two calculations...
    int smll, mdm, lg, xl;
    //Validate the inputs can be converted and set the appropriate variable values at the same time
    if (Int32.TryParse(txtSmall.Text, out smll) //using TryParse sets the integer variable values only if they can successfully be converted
        && Int32.TryParse(txtMedium.Text, out mdm)
        && Int32.TryParse(txtLarge.Text, out lg)
        && Int32.TryParse(txtExtralarge.Text, out xl)
        )
    {
        int ttl = smll + mdm + lg + xl;
        double GrandTotal, TagsCollars;
        TagsCollars = ttl;
        GrandTotal = TagsCollars * .285 * 315;

        txtTags.Text = $"{TagsCollars:#,##0}"; //Resharper suggested simplification of String.Format("{0:#,##0}", TagsCollars)....I believe ReSharper
        txtCollars.Text = $"{TagsCollars:#,##0}";
        lblGrandtotal.Text = $"{(GrandTotal + TagsCollars + TagsCollars):#,###,##0}";

    }

}
```

This will get the job done but it's pretty inflexible. Each input has to successfully convert to an integer or this will fail. A better, more time consuming approach would be something like this:

```
    int smll;//, mdm, lg, xl;
    try
    {
        smll = Convert.ToInt32(txtSmall.Text);

    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        smll = 0;
        //txtSmall.Text value can't be converted to an integer
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //some other issue occurred and you're probably better off just exiting entirely
        return;
    }
```

There are more flexible approaches out there, such as using number styles and such but, their flexibility comes at the price of you having to be more aware of the impact of what and how you're coding. Sometimes it's just safer to train your customers than write code you're not confident with.

Comment: thank you! ill look into this :) btw visual studio wont accept some of the code you provided: 

txtTags.Text = $"{TagsCollars:#,##0}"; //Resharper suggested simplification of String.Format("{0:#,##0}", TagsCollars)....I believe ReSharper
        txtCollars.Text = $"{TagsCollars:#,##0}";
        lblGrandtotal.Text = $"{(GrandTotal + TagsCollars + TagsCollars):#,###,##0}";

they had red underlines at the beginning of $ onwards

Comment: Those `$` are a new feature of C# 6. Replace those with `string.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse an integer in lblGrantotal.Text, but you are getting a FormatException, which means the text in lblGranTotal isn't recognized as a number. Maybe you are using comma **,** instead of point **.** as decimal separator, or something like that.